# Fine tuning Resnet 50 Cant good accuracy and validation is small how i can improve?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, artificial-intelligence

Im newbie for deeplearning use the FER 2013 dataset using resnet 50 model
I have tried various learning rates from various ranges example im using ADAM Optimizer with LR= 0.0008, but the accuracy and validation models are not good getting Overfitting or Underfitting How improve my models using Resnet 50?

I want models target to be above 50% optimal without overfitting or underfitting.

this is what I have done for more:
https://github.com/senapahlevi/FER2013-CNN-Resnet-/commits/master/vanilla
These my Code with LR= 0.0008

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Input,Dense
from keras.applications import ResNet50
from keras.applications.resnet50 import preprocess_input
from livelossplot import PlotLossesKeras
from keras.optimizers import Adam
from keras import optimizers
from keras.layers.convolutional import Conv2D,MaxPooling2D,SeparableConv2D
from keras.layers.core import Dropout,Flatten,Dense
from keras.layers.normalization import BatchNormalization
from sklearn import metrics 
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
#from keras_hist_graph import plot_history


num_classesft =7
image_resizeft = 48
batch_size_trainingft = 64
batch_size_validationft = 64

path_trainingft = '/content/drive/MyDrive/UjicobaFER/FER2013/train'
path_validationft = '/content/drive/MyDrive/UjicobaFER/FER2013/validation'

data_generator =ImageDataGenerator(
    preprocessing_function = preprocess_input
)

training_generator = data_generator.flow_from_directory(
    path_trainingft,
    target_size = (image_resizeft,image_resizeft),
    batch_size = batch_size_trainingft,
    class_mode='categorical')

validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    path_validationft,
    target_size = (image_resizeft,image_resizeft),
    batch_size = batch_size_validationft,
    class_mode='categorical',
)

model = Sequential()

model.add(ResNet50(
    include_top = False,
    pooling='avg',
    weights='imagenet',
))

model.add(Dense(num_classesft,activation='softmax'))
model.layers
model.layers[0].layers
model.layers[0].trainable = False
model.summary()
model.compile(optimizer=optimizers.Adam(lr = 0.0008),loss='categorical_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])
steps_per_epoch_training = len(training_generator)/batch_size_trainingft
steps_per_epoch_validation = len(validation_generator)/batch_size_validationft
num_epochs = 45

fit_history = model.fit(
    training_generator,
    steps_per_epoch = steps_per_epoch_training,
    epochs = num_epochs,
    validation_data=validation_generator,
    validation_steps = steps_per_epoch_validation,
    verbose=1)
```

[RESULT MY MODEL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IoVF5.png)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you have too few trainable parameters. This happens because you have used 'imagenet' weights and you are not training ResNet from scratch. I would suggest the following:

**1. You could add another dense layer before the Dense layer:**

```
model.add(Dense(num_classesft,activation='softmax'))
```

for example:

```
model.add(Dense(250,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
```

this would add a Fully Connected layer after the feature extraction layers of the ResNet.

**2. You could train ResNet from scratch**

To do this, just alter the code:

```
model.add(ResNet50(
include_top = False,
pooling='avg',
weights='imagenet'))
```

to this:

```
model.add(ResNet50(
include_top = False,
pooling='avg',
weights=None))
```

**3. Use Heavier Data Augmentation**

**4. Experiment with different learning rates**

Comment: hi when i follow your step on point no 2,  getting error when run model.layers[0].layers output  'ModuleWrapper' object has no attribute 'layers' , and also getting error after run model.summary() output: This model has not yet been built. Build the model first by calling `build()` or calling `fit()` with some data, or specify an `input_shape` argument in the first layer(s) for automatic build.

Comment: In that case, you could keep the code as it is: " model.add(ResNet50(
include_top = False,
pooling='avg',
weights='imagenet')) ". And then do "model.layers[0].trainable = True"

Comment: hi Giannis on point no 1 would you like give me suggestion build another dense layer for my models because im very beginner and didnt know exactly build paramater for dense layer for avoiding overfitting and underfitting on FER 2013 dataset because i have a lot trials and error then result are not satisfying

Comment: I would suggest reading a tutorial mate. There are plenty of those out there. The main idea of point 1 is that the Resnet is processing the image and extracts features from it. Those features should be further processed by dense layers (or e.g. SVM, LSTM) afterward.